# Placing Date.getDate() as an array index return undefined in an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm stumped on why this returns undefined. Any ideas?

```
        weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
                
                
        getDay() {
           let date = new Date();
           let num = 2;
                  
           console.log('weekday: ', this.weekdays[date.getDate()]);    
           // 'weekday: undefined'
           console.log('weekday: ', this.weekdays[num]); 
           // 'weekday: Tuesday'
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today is September 7th, so `new Date().getDate()` returns `7` since it returns the day of the month.
There is no element at position `7`, the last index of your array is `6` (the first index is `0`), therefore it returns undefined.

You need [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), it returns the day of the week (Sunday = 0)

```js
getDay() {
    const date = new Date();
    const num = 2;

    console.log('weekday: ', this.weekdays[date.getDay()]);    
    // 'weekday: Thursday'
    console.log('weekday: ', this.weekdays[num]); 
    // 'weekday: Tuesday'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript date getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time. The value returned by getDate() is an integer between 1 and 31.

Taking into consideration as your current date as 9/8/2023 your code will return value as 8 which is undefined in your array.

```
console.log('weekday: ', this.weekdays[date.getDate()]);
//weekdays[8] does not contain any value hence it is undefined
```